# How to pass customized parameters to SOlR DIH query

Tags: java, oracle, solr, solrj, dataimporthandler

I have scenario where i need to pass customized parameters to solr data import query.

Ex- `select * from customer where last_updated_date >=last_updated_indexed_date`

The `last_updated_indexed_date` is coming from another table which has details about core.

How can I pass that `last_indexed_updated_date` in `DIH` query.

Comment: If it's coming from another table, can't you do a regular SQL join?

Comment: Did you tried the same by passing using the request param?

Comment: yes, as @MatsLindh suggested you can go for a sql join

Comment: I have not tried that , Let me try that one.

Answer (score 1):

The `data-config` can be configured something like below :

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource name="ds-db" driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:test" user="dev" password="dev" />
    <dataSource name="ds-file" type="BinFileDataSource" />
    <document name="documents">
        <entity name="book" dataSource="ds-db"
            query="select distinct
    book.id as id,
    book.title,
    book.author,
    book.publisher,
    from Books book
    where book.book_added_date >= to_date($ {dataimporter.request.lastIndexDate}, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')))"

            transformer="DateFormatTransformer">
            <field column=”id” name=”id” />
            <field column=”title” name=”title” />
            <field column=”author” name=”author” />
            <field column=”publisher” name=”publisher” />
            <entity name=”content” query=”select description from content
                where content_id='${book.Id}' ”>
                <field column=”description” name=”description” />
            </entity>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

The way here `'${book.Id}'` is retrieved and passed to another query. You will also need to work upon something similar for the `last_indexed_updated_date` in your `data-config.xml`. if you don't have the same in your tables. You can try the same passing to the data import url like `lastIndexDate`(Please refer the below data import url.)

The data import url will be be like

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/admin/select/?qt=/dataimport&command=full-import&clean=false&commit=true&lastIndexDate='08/05/2011 20:16:11'
```

Comment: I wish you could have posted the question...thank you...:)